# iCalendar Valarm doesn't work

Tags: icalendar

I generate iCal file like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Splash//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20150912
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20150912
SUMMARY:test
DESCRIPTION:xxx
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:test
TRIGGER:-P0DT16H0M0S
END:VALARM
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:test
TRIGGER:-P1DT16H0M0S
END:VALARM
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:test
TRIGGER:-P2DT16H0M0S
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And when i import this file with google calendar import is successful but i don't have reminders so what i do wrong with VALARM and how can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have a similar problem and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47071369/valarm-is-ignored-by-ios-calendar-but-works-on-macos-calendar) says it can be made to work by adding some properties but I can't get that to work either..

Answer (score 2):

Your icalendar file does not validate, it is missing the UID at DTSTAMP properties. Try adding those properties and see if the alarms work.

[iCalendar Validator](http://icalendar.org/validator.html)

Comment: even if the ical is valid, the valarm may will be ignored - it seems valarm will be overwritten / ignored by some client softwares on import.. :-/