# VALARM is ignored by iOS Calendar, but works on MacOS Calendar

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, calendar, icalendar

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170926T114940Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20170926T114940Z
CREATED:20170921T105157Z
SEQUENCE:435463
ORGANIZER;CN=Blockchain Slovakia:MAILTO:noreply@facebookmail.com
DTSTART:20171003T170000Z
DTEND:20171003T200000Z
UID:e118297045503751@facebook.com
SUMMARY:Bitcoin Meetup Bratislava 3.10.2017
LOCATION:Zámocký pivovar
URL:https://www.facebook.com/events/118297045503751/
DESCRIPTION:Bitcoin Meetup
CLASS:PUBLIC
STATUS:CONFIRMED
PARTSTAT:TENTATIVE
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT30M
REPEAT:1
DURATION:PT15M
DESCRIPTION:FB Event Alert
ACTION:DISPLAY
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

[https://github.com/olso/facebook-cals-alert/blob/master/stdlib-workspace/olso/facebook-cals-alert/functions/**main**.js](https://github.com/olso/facebook-cals-alert/blob/master/stdlib-workspace/olso/facebook-cals-alert/functions/__main__.js)

`VALARM` works for MacOS but I can't get it to work on iOS

`MacOS 10.12.6`
`iOS 11.0.3`

Also another bug, `MacOS` keeps resetting these settings, haven't observed why, yet.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIC6L.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it...

`VALARM` needs to have `UID` and `X-WR-ALARMUID`

Comment: Have you by any chance got a full text of the working vcalendar file for this? I'm facing the same issue as you (ios ignores the alarm events) but adding these proeprties to my VALARM doesn't seem to work for my iOS12..